# Matching two sets of strings from multi lines using Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Anyone can help me to create pattern in regex capturing as results/matches below? Tried the below pattern it works only if the next string is on the same line not with the nextline

```
 Pattern: (?<= <abc xyz=“123>\n<def id=“the_quick_brown_fox)(?s)[A-Z0-9]{9}

<abc xyz=“123>
<def id=“the_quick_brown_foxABC123456” the1andonly

Akfkfkfjfjfjf fkdkfkfkfkf dkdkfkfk
1445gkfkfkfk rkfkfkfkfk tkfkfkfk

<abc xyz=“123>
<def id=“the_quick_brown_foxDEF123456” the1andonly

Dkckfkfkf rifkfkqq fkfkfkqq tkfkfk
Qkekfjj ffkfkf krkfkfk wkkdkfkf rkfkf

<abc xyz=“123>
<def id=“the_quick_brown_foxGHI123456” the1andonly

Matched:
ABC123456
DEF123456
GHI123456
```

Comment: Just change the space between the 2 tags with `\s+`

Comment: It matches in regex101 but not with notedpad++ as I want to mark all matches in notepad++

Comment: You have a space before `<abc...` remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<abc xyz=“123>\R<def id=“the_quick_brown_fox\s*\K[A-Z0-9]{9}
```

*Details*:

- `<abc xyz=“123>` - a literal text
- `\R`- line break
- `<def id=“the_quick_brown_fox` - literal text
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - forget the text matched so far
- `[A-Z0-9]{9}` - nine alphanumerics.